When are (Globe?) Artichokes ready to Harvest?
Last year I grew some artichokes (can't remember why - I think I was given some seeds and was just learning).    I know very little about artichokes -  I did not get a harvest last year, but just noticed some artichokes growing on one of my plants and I wonder if - ignoring "bang for buck" - they can be harvested at any time prior to them flowering or if they need to be at a certain growth/size before they are any good for eating.
Specifically I am wondering if the below specimen is ready to harvest (and if not, when it will be) -


They are (all) harvested when immature, and harvesting them at any point of immaturity will work, so long as you are not seeking "the biggest you can get." There are some advantages to not growing them as long as possible - while they will be smaller, a greater percentage of each leaf will be edible at the earlier stage of development, in my experience.
If you were only looking for the heart, as what's commonly found in cans, that would be much smaller. But if you are cooking and eating the whole thing, the leaves being more edible compensate for a smaller heart.

You can harvest any time before the heads begin to open up in the center. If you leave them too long a tuft of purple flowers will poke out of the top, reminiscent of a giant thistle(which artichokes are anyway).
